# What are the characteristics of a motor that will generate current and is powered by a 30 cc, 2-stroke small engine?

Tags: motors, torque, mechanical, power, generator

**Problem**: I am trying to hobby-build a generator using a (old, working, throw-away gas, yard blower) 30 cc, 2-stroke engine.  The 2-stroke engine will spin a motor and I want the motor to generate DC current.

**My research**:

- Normal small-fan motor without magnets will NOT work; and if it does, it is extremely inefficient
- Ideally, one should use a brushed, DC motor to generate the power
- A DC motor used as a generator typically has permanent magnets
- Brushed DC motor is preferred to brushless DC motor (not sure why)
- Brushed motors may be spun/rotated in either direction (CW, CCW); however, one direction (CW) is preferred and slightly more efficient
- One can generate AC current from a DC source using an inverter/converter
- Ideal building blocks: (input) gas/oil mix --> run 2-stroke-engine --> spin brushed DC motor --> generate DC power --> charge a 12 volts car battery (12-volt 1ah; 12 DCV) --> 12 VDC to 120 VAC Inverter/Converter --> 120 AC current (output)

**What I have tried**:

- I used a small-fan 120-volt AC motor (without a permanent magnet) and realized that it will not work; it generates very little power
- I did google-searches and found some small cheap brushed DC motors on Amazon [e.g. 12/24V 30W High Speed CW/CCW Permanent Magnet DC Motor For DIY Generator (DC 12V 3000RPM)]. Interestingly, its comments/description on Amazon says “The stator windings of the motor are copper wire…” this confused me since I believed that in a DC motor with permanent magnets, the stator is the permanent magnets; i.e. it is not based on stator windings. Also, the motor’s physical dimensions are 1.97 x 1.18 x 1.97 inches.  It seems rather small (physically).  Is this unit good enough? Will it overheat?

Comment: Try a car alternator - controlling the field current controls the output & therefore the load.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I had thought about it initially since an alternator would convert and directly produce AC power;  however, I decided to first check other alternatives as an alternator is a bit costly (minimum ~$60 for used item).  I will keep it in mind as I would not (then) need an inverter or battery. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the cheap way to proceed.

First, find you a *battery-powered* weedeater that is second-hand, or a discard. disassemble and test the motor for operation. If it operates, now you have a generator that has almost exactly the right power output for your application, because in its previous lifetime *it was a motor in the same application as the little gas engine you have in hand*.

Then you couple the electric motor shaft to the gas engine shaft and connect the output of the motor to a *full-wave bridge rectifier* that has the same voltage rating as the generator's output, and enough current capacity to manage the power output of the generator- which will be close to the power *consumption* of the generator in its previous life.

This sounds like a cool project and I hope you have fun building it!

Comment: Good idea.  Never thought about this novel approach. Thanks.